# How can I insert a tree of nodes with namespaces into an existing XML file using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I've been using Nokogiri to generate an XML file (specifically, a GraphML document using some yEd namespaces). An example of the type of file I'm generating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:java="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-common/1.0/java" xmlns:sys="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-common/markup/primitives/2.0" xmlns:x="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-common/markup/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:y="http://www.yworks.com/xml/graphml" xmlns:yed="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yed/3" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
  <key attr.name="Description" attr.type="string" for="graph" id="d0"/>
  <key attr.name="description" attr.type="string" for="node" id="d5"/>
  <key for="node" id="d6" yfiles.type="nodegraphics"/>
  <key for="graphml" id="d7" yfiles.type="resources"/>
  <key attr.name="description" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d9"/>
  <key for="edge" id="d10" yfiles.type="edgegraphics"/>
  <graph edgedefault="directed" id="G">
    <data key="d0"/>
    <node id="n10">
      <data key="d5"/>
      <data key="d6">
        <y:ShapeNode>
          <y:Geometry width="42.42640687119285" height="42.42640687119285" x="30.0" y="0.0"/>
          <y:Fill color="#DBDCDF" transparent="false"/>
          <y:BorderStyle color="#303236" raised="false" type="line" width="1.0"/>
          <y:NodeLabel alignment="center" fontFamily="Source Sans Pro Semibold" fontSize="17" fontStyle="plain" verticalTextPosition="bottom" horizontalTextPosition="center">DAY</y:NodeLabel>
          <y:Shape type="ellipse"/>
        </y:ShapeNode>
      </data>
    </node>
    <node id="n11">
      <data key="d5"/>
      <data key="d6">
        <y:ShapeNode>
          <y:Geometry width="30.0" height="30.0" x="-14.999999999999993" y="25.980762113533164"/>
          <y:Fill color="#DBDCDF" transparent="false"/>
          <y:BorderStyle color="#303236" raised="false" type="line" width="1.0"/>
          <y:NodeLabel alignment="center" fontFamily="Source Sans Pro Semibold" fontSize="12" fontStyle="plain" verticalTextPosition="bottom" horizontalTextPosition="center">STL</y:NodeLabel>
          <y:Shape type="ellipse"/>
        </y:ShapeNode>
      </data>
    </node>
    <node id="n12">
      <data key="d5"/>
      <data key="d6">
        <y:ShapeNode>
          <y:Geometry width="42.42640687119285" height="42.42640687119285" x="-15.000000000000014" y="-25.980762113533153"/>
          <y:Fill color="#DBDCDF" transparent="false"/>
          <y:BorderStyle color="#303236" raised="false" type="line" width="1.0"/>
          <y:NodeLabel alignment="center" fontFamily="Source Sans Pro Semibold" fontSize="17" fontStyle="plain" verticalTextPosition="bottom" horizontalTextPosition="center">DFW</y:NodeLabel>
          <y:Shape type="ellipse"/>
        </y:ShapeNode>
      </data>
    </node>
    <edge id="e0" source="n10" target="n11">
      <data key="d9"/>
      <data key="d10">
        <y:PolyLineEdge>
          <y:LineStyle width="2.0" color="#ff99cc"/>
          <y:Arrows source="none" target="standard"/>
          <y:EdgeLabel visible="false">American Airlines</y:EdgeLabel>
        </y:PolyLineEdge>
      </data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="e1" source="n11" target="n12">
      <data key="d9"/>
      <data key="d10">
        <y:PolyLineEdge>
          <y:LineStyle width="2.0" color="#ff99cc"/>
          <y:Arrows source="none" target="standard"/>
          <y:EdgeLabel visible="false">American Airlines</y:EdgeLabel>
        </y:PolyLineEdge>
      </data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="e2" source="n12" target="n10">
      <data key="d9"/>
      <data key="d10">
        <y:PolyLineEdge>
          <y:LineStyle width="2.0" color="#ff99cc"/>
          <y:Arrows source="none" target="standard"/>
          <y:EdgeLabel visible="false">American Airlines</y:EdgeLabel>
        </y:PolyLineEdge>
      </data>
    </edge>
  </graph>
  <data key="d7">
    <y:Resources/>
  </data>
</graphml>
```

The document has a basic structure that doesn't change from document to document, and then a collection of `<node>` and `<edge>` tags specific to each document.

I've been able to successfully build this XML in a single method using Nokogiri::XML::Builder.

However, I now want to generate this file based on a different type of data as well -- most of the file will be unchanged; only my code that loops over data and generates the `<node>` and `<edge>` tags will change. So I'm effectively trying to create an XML template that I can call from multiple Ruby methods, which will then insert their own variants.

My thought was that I could save an XML file with everything except the `<node>` and `<edge>` tags. I would then have each different method use Nokogiri::XML::Builder to create a DocumentFragment of `<node>` and `<edge>` tags, open the template file, and insert the DocumentFragment in as a child of the `<graph>` tag:

```
YED_TEMPLATE = "#{Rails.root}/app/views/xml_templates/flights.yed.graphml"

def self.yed_from_string(flight_string)
  airports = flight_string.split(/[,-]/).tally

  output = File.open(YED_TEMPLATE) {|f| Nokogiri::XML(f)}

  nodes = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse("")
  Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(nodes) do |xml|
    airports.map{|airport, visits| yed_airport_node(xml, airport, airport, visits)}
  end

  # Write similar code for edges

  output.at("graph").add_child(nodes)
  return output.to_xml
end

private

def self.yed_airport_node(xml, id, text, visits)
  xml.node(id: "n#{id}") do
    xml.data(key: "d5")
    xml.data(key: "d6") do
      xml[:y].ShapeNode do
        xml[:y].Geometry(circle_size(visits))
        xml[:y].Fill(color: BASE_STYLES[:node_color_fill], transparent: false)
        xml[:y].BorderStyle(color: BASE_STYLES[:node_color_border], raised: false, type: "line", width: BASE_STYLES[:node_width_border])
        xml[:y].NodeLabel(text, **font(visits))
        xml[:y].Shape(type: "ellipse")
      end
    end
  end
  return nil
end

# Write similar method for edges
```

So this code largely does what I want it to. It successfully loads the template XML file at YED_TEMPLATE, it successfully creates a DocumentFragment, and it successfully inserts the DocumentFragment into the template XML...

...as long as I don't include the `y` namespace tags (`y:ShapeNode`, `y:Geometry`, etc.). If I do, I get an `ArgumentError (Namespace y has not been defined)`.

That makes sense to me, since the DocumentFragment isn't aware of all of the namespace definitions in the template XML file. But I have no idea how to actually provide the namespaces to a DocumentFragment, since it doesn't have a true root tag to add them to; the real root is in the template file.

Is there a way for me to pass namespace definitions into a Nokogiri::XML::Builder for a DocumentFragment? Alternatively, is there a better way for me to create a collection of nested tags with namespaces, and insert them into an existing XML document?

Comment: We need more information; What is your desired output? Add the very smallest XML that represents exactly what you are trying to generate to your question. Don't add "updated" or "edit" tags, just add it where you would have if it'd been included originally. Where would the added tags go in that document? Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Adding tags to a document is easy but it's not obvious what you want where.

Comment: One thing that people don't seem to grasp with Nokogiri, is that any place in the documentation that says a parameter can be `node_or_tags`, For instance, "`Add node_or_tags as a child of this Node. node_or_tags can be a Nokogiri::XML::Node, a ::DocumentFragment, a ::NodeSet, or a string containing markup.`". So, `"<foo><bar>hello world!</bar></foo>"` could be passed in and Nokogiri will parse it and create a fragment and do whatever that method does. This can make life easier.

Comment: @theTinMan That's good to know, and if all else fails, I can certainly generate a string with the XML I want to insert easily enough. But if I'm going to be generating an XML string of any complexity, I feel like I should be using an XML builder to do it; my problem is that I can't seem to build a subset of the document on its own because that subset isn't aware of the namespaces defined in the main document it hasn't been attached to yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nifty little tick if you want to create a builder instance scoped to a namespace is to use `Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(doc.root)`:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:y="foo"></root>')
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(doc.root) do |xml|
  xml['y'].Shapenode do |sn|
    sn.Foo
    sn.Bar
  end
end
```

`builder.to_xml` outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:y="foo">
  <y:Shapenode>
     <y:Foo/>
     <y:Bar/>
  </y:Shapenode>
</root>
```

Worth noting though is that it mutates `doc`. If I where to do this I would use `Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(doc.root.dup)` which prevents it from mutating the arguments.

You can also just create builders with any arbitrary root with:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root('xmlns:y' => 'bar') do
    xml['y'].Shapenode
  end
end
```

`builder.doc.xpath('/*').children` will slice out the node set.

Comment: I ended up using the second strategy (builder with an arbitrary root), then appending it to my template with `template.at("graph").add_child(builder.at("root").children)`. This was exactly what I needed to get it working, thank you!